# Not fetching results with cts:json-property-scope-query

Tags: json, marklogic-9

Document has below JSONproperty:

```
 "Age":{
      "child":true,
      "adult":true
      
   }
```

I ran the below query, but didn't get any results

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:json-property-scope-query("Age", cts:json-property-scope-query("child","true")))
```

Also which is better, to store this json property for fast searches

```
"Age": ["child","adult"]
```

OR

```
"Age":{
  "child":true,
  "adult":true,
  "elder":false
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a value-query as inner query? You also may wanna try using boolean value `true` if your data is boolean, and `"true"` if your data is string.

Comment: Yes, it worked with cts:search(doc(), cts:json-property-scope-query("Age", cts:json-property-value-query("child",fn:true()))).Can you also let me knw which is better way to store this data in an arrary or nested json with boolean values.

Comment: 'better' depends on the use case I'd say. Array is denser, but nested boolean properties gives more expressiveness. Nested booleans make it easier doing a negated search (elder = false)

Answer (score 1):

JSON property values will be indexed as their string, numeric, or boolean types.

Use a [`cts:json-property-value-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:json-property-value-query) and search for the boolean `true()`, not the string `"true"`.

```
cts:search(doc(), 
  cts:json-property-scope-query("Age", 
    cts:json-property-value-query("child", true())))
```